# Removing non Printable values aftert Encoding.ASCII.GetString()

Tags: c#, string, encoding, byte, non-printing-characters

Suppose I have a Byte array and I use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` to convert the bytes into a string. Now the first few bytes will contain actual values, but the remaining ones will all have value of **0**. After obtaining the string, when I show it on a WPF Form, there are some non printable characters. How can I remove these non printable characters. One way would be to loop through the array and only consider up to an index not containing **0**, but I may also Encode using Unicode, that is `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()`.

What would be the most generic way to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you know the actual encoding of the Byte array?  I'm imagining the input array to be Chinese, UTF8 encoding, for example.

Comment: @tofutim: Yes, I know the actual encoding that is being used, but as I mentioned, it will vary from scenario to scenario.

Comment: Are you insuring for when the encoding is unknown and you choose ASCII?  Converting from a foreign language could lead to diamonds and hearts, etc.  Do you just mean to strip those weird ASCII non-characters like beeps?  How about linefeeds and tabs?

Comment: @tofutim: There are no line feeds and tabs. It will be some characters and the remaining of the byte array will be zero. Had it been just ASCII Encoding, I would just look for first zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var buffer = new byte[] { 65, 66, 67, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
var length = buffer.TakeWhile(b => b != 0).Count();
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
```

Comment: what if there was a character where the first bytes are 0?

Comment: In UTF-8 (and ASCII too) a zero byte is never part of a character. It can safety be used as a string terminator.

Comment: Thanks, just one note is TakeWhile defined in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Yes. TakeWhile is in the System.Linq namespace for .NET 3.5.

Comment: It didn't show up on Visual Studio auto-complete. I am declaring the type as byte[] and not var. Could this have something to do with that? In case, I ran a loop and your suggestion is working fine.

Comment: (1) At the top of your class file add "using System.Linq". (2) In Project Settings check that your .NET Framework version is 3.5 or above. (3) In Project References make sure "System.Core" appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just find the first zero in the array and strip off everything that follows.